# Error when making requests using headers

Tags: python, api

I am trying to make a request to a url with some headers and it doesn't seem to be working. I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE7d5.png) (TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object)

```
import time
from rauth.service import OAuth1Service
import oauth
import rauth
import hmac
import requests
import oauth2 as oauth1

url = 'https://secure.trademe.co.nz/Oauth/RequestToken?scope=MyTradeMeRead,MyTradeMeWrite '

headers = {'oauth_callback': "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback", 
          'oauth_consumer_key' : "C74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422" ,
          'oauth_version': 1.0,
          'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
          'oauth_nonce' : oauth1.generate_nonce(),
          'oauth_signature_method' : "HMAC-SHA1",
          'oauth_signature' : "5s3%2Bel078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY%3D"
          }


r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

***following this:***

> To make the Authorization header, you simply append all the values starting with “OAuth”. Each value must be URL encoded.

```
1. Authorization: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.website-tm-access.co.nz%2Ftrademe-callback",
> oauth_consumer_key="C74CD73FDBE37D29BDD21BAB54BC70E422",
> oauth_version="1.0", oauth_timestamp="1285532322",
> oauth_nonce="7O3kEe", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
> oauth_signature="5s3%2Bel078a5AXGi43FBDyfg5yWY%3D"
```

> We can finally make
>   a request to the server. By making a request to
>   https://secure.trademe.co.nz/Oauth/RequestToken?scope=MyTradeMeRead,MyTradeMeWrite
>   with the Authorization header, we should get back an oauth_token and
>   oauth_token_secret.
>
> `oauth_token=86EE20AFF655C34CB34873449A5F98020B&oauth_token_secret=905448B594595D5A030DC68BE40AE03C2B&oauth_callback_confirmed=true`

Comment: To make your question more useful for others, please post the resulting error message (wich is in fact the stack trace of an exception), right away it in the question and as text, rather than linking an image. This question may be useful long after the image is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you pass something else than a string as header value. And indeed,

```
 'oauth_version': 1.0,
 'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time()),
```

pass numeric values rather than string values. Make this strings and let's see whether it works.

Comment: using 'oauth_version': "1.0",  'oauth_timestamp': "21" seemed to work

Comment: consider accepting the answer in that case ;) And, just for reference, have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ It's really cool.